# Why does this page load with the left column text so much larger than right when using Chrome Android only?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, html-table

Why does this page load with the left column text so much larger than right column of the table which makes up this code running only on Google Chrome for Android? Is it my code or the software?

Any help or suggestions on how to touch up my code would be appreciated.

This is a screen shot of what it looks like in Google Chrome on an Android GalaxyS3. On most other browsers that I could find it does not enlarge the text on the left. I have tried changing all the div styles to make sure they are all identical and that did not help. I have tried using different fonts and headings and still no luck. I would like to get it to work right as this is a popular browser.

I really have looked at this code a lot, which is based on a template for an auction listing, to figure out why it was doing this. Found it puzzling why if if you view the code on a desktop browser, or on an iPhone Safari or even Firefox running on Android it loads correct.

As you can see in the image below. This is what the page looks like when loaded on Google Chrome on Android Ver. 51.02704.81
[image]

Thanks

```
<!--Description Template-->
<div align="center" style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
  <div align="center">
    <table width="1155" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: 0px solid rgb(178, 206, 207);">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="background-color: rgb(216, 227, 227);">
            <div style="padding-left: 12px; padding-top: 12px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
              Apple 60W MagSafe Power Adapter A1234 (for MacBook and 13-inch MacBook Pro)
              <p>&nbsp;</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 626px;" width="1" height="11" alt=""></td>
          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100px;" width="100" height="11" alt=""></td>
          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100px;" width="100" height="11" alt=""></td>
          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100px;" width="100" height="11" alt=""></td>
          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 38px;" width="38" height="11" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <table width="1155" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-top: 0px; border: 1px solid rgb(178, 206, 207);">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="text-align: center; padding: 12px;">
              <div style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                &nbsp;
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>
                  <img border="0" src="http://i68.tinypic.com/2ekkf86.jpg" width="643" height="339"></p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <div align="left">
                  <table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top: 24px;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" style="background-color: rgb(216, 227, 227);">
                          <div style="padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 6px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                            <font face="Georgia">PAYMENT INFORMATION</font></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: rgb(178, 206, 207); width: 374px;" width="1" height="6" alt=""></td>
                        <td style="background-color: rgb(80, 208, 125); width: 50px;" width="50" height="6" alt=""></td>
                        <td style="background-color: rgb(208, 37, 82); width: 56px;" width="50" height="6" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <p><font face="Georgia" size="3">P<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">Lorem</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)"> 
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mi tortor, porttitor 
vel sollicitudin at, ornare vel ipsum.</span></font></p>
                  <p><font face="Georgia" size="3">
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">&nbsp;Fusce 
vestibulum arcu a quam posuere pulvinar. </span></font></p>
                  <p><font face="Georgia" size="3">
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
Nulla quis gravida mauris. Duis dapibus id nisi sed iaculis. Donec tincidunt 
commodo felis et pharetra. Ut quis tincidunt neque, ac facilisis dolor. 
Vestibulum eu hendrerit neque.</span></font></p>
                  <p><font face="Georgia" size="3">
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">&nbsp;Aliquam 
placerat arcu vel imperdiet dictum. Pellentesque et libero eu erat tincidunt 
imperdiet quis lobortis urna.</span><br>
&nbsp;</font></p>
                  <p style="text-align: center">
                    <img border="0" src="http://i68.tinypic.com/156wsc7.jpg" width="288" height="109"></p>
                </div>
                <div align="left">
                  <table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top: 24px;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" style="background-color: rgb(216, 227, 227);">
                          <div style="padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 6px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                            <font face="Georgia">SHIPPING INFORMATION</font></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: rgb(178, 206, 207); width: 374px;" width="1" height="6" alt=""></td>
                        <td style="background-color: rgb(80, 208, 125); width: 50px;" width="50" height="6" alt=""></td>
                        <td style="background-color: rgb(208, 37, 82); width: 56px;" width="50" height="6" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <div style="font-size: 13px; margin-top: 12px;">
                  <p style="text-align: left">
                    <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Georgia; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
<font size="3">itae tortor. Ut facilisis tortor nisl. Integer posuere, ante non 
varius maximus, leo risus imperdiet nibh, feugiat maximus velit </font></span>
                  </p>
                  <p style="text-align: left">
                    <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Georgia; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
<font size="3">dui suscipit tellus. Vivamus sed turpis vitae elit blandit </font>
</span></p>
                  <p style="text-align: left">
                    <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Georgia; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
<font size="3">condimentum. Curabitur elementum finibus tempor. Vivamus ultrices 
lectus tortor, vitae luctus quam pulvinar sed.</font></span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="img/spacer.gif" width="12" height="1" alt=""></td>
          <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 492px;">
            <div style="margin-right: 12px; margin-top: 12px; margin-bottom: 12px;">
              <table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="background-color: rgb(216, 227, 227);">
                      <div style="padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 6px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                        DESCRIPTION OF THIS ITEM</div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: rgb(178, 206, 207); width: 374px;" width="1" height="6" alt=""></td>
                    <td style="background-color: rgb(80, 208, 125); width: 50px;" width="50" height="6" alt=""></td>
                    <td style="background-color: rgb(208, 37, 82); width: 56px;" width="50" height="6" alt=""></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <div style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 12px;">
                <font face="Georgia" size="4">
<span style="font-weight: 400; text-decoration: underline">BRAND NEW OUT OF BOX&nbsp; 
Genuine Apple replacement part <br>
<br>
</span><span style="font-weight: 400"><br>
The 60 Watt MagSafe Power Adapter features a magnetic DC connector that ensures 
your power cable will disconnect if it experiences undue strain and helps 
prevent fraying or weakening of the cables over time. In addition, the magnetic 
DC helps guide the plug into the system for a quick and secure connection.<br>
When the connection is secure, an LED located at the head of the DC connector 
will light; an amber light lets you know that your portable is charging, while a 
green light tells you that you have a full charge. <br>
<br>
<br>
Compatible with MacBook and 13-inch MacBook Pro.<br>
<br>
Output: 16.5V 3.65A, 60W adapter</span></font></div>
              <table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top: 24px;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="background-color: rgb(216, 227, 227);">
                      <div style="padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 6px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                        ABOUT&nbsp; RETURNS
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: rgb(178, 206, 207); width: 374px;" width="1" height="6" alt=""></td>
                    <td style="background-color: rgb(80, 208, 125); width: 50px;" width="50" height="6" alt=""></td>
                    <td style="background-color: rgb(208, 37, 82); width: 56px;" width="50" height="6" alt=""></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <div style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 12px;">
                <p align="center">
                  <font face="Georgia" size="3">30 day Money Back Guarantee
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
onec tincidunt commodo felis et pharetra. Ut quis tincidunt neque, ac facilisis 
dolor. Vestibulum eu hend</span></font></div>
              <table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="31" style="margin-top: 24px;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="background-color: rgb(216, 227, 227);">
                      <div style="padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 6px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                        <font face="Georgia">OTHER INFORMATION</font></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: rgb(178, 206, 207); width: 374px;" width="1" height="6" alt=""></td>
                    <td style="background-color: rgb(80, 208, 125); width: 50px;" width="50" height="6" alt=""></td>
                    <td style="background-color: rgb(208, 37, 82); width: 56px;" width="50" height="6" alt=""></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <div style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 12px;">
                <p align="left">
                  <span style="font-family: Georgia; font-weight: 700"><font size="4">Qornare.&nbsp; or 
rna to ornare. us?</font></span><span id="PLayout_lbl5" style="font-family: Georgia;"><br>
&nbsp;<br>
</span><font face="Georgia" size="3">
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
Nulla quis gravida mauris. Duis dapibus id nisi sed iaculis. Donec tincidunt 
commodo felis et pharetra. Ut quis tincidunt neque, ac facilisis dolor. 
Vestibulum eu hendrerit neque</span></font></p>
                <p align="left">
                  <font face="Georgia" size="3">
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: 2; text-align: justify; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
Nulla quis gravida mauris. Duis dapibus id nisi sed iaculis. Donec tincidunt 
commodo felis et pharetra. Ut quis tincidunt neque, ac facilisis dolor. 
Vestibulum eu hendrerit neque</span></font></p>
                <p align="center">
                  <img src="http://shapeglobe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/cs-icon.png"></p>
                <p align="center"><b><font size="3" face="Georgia">Thanks for viewing this item!</font></b></p>
              </div>
              <div align="center" style="background-color: rgb(216, 227, 227); border: 1px solid rgb(178, 206, 207); padding: 6px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 24px;">
                <font face="Georgia">eBay Seller<br>
&nbsp;</font></div>
              <div align="center" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 6px;">
                ©2016 </div>
              <div style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; letter-spacing: 1px; text-transform: uppercase; color: rgb(145, 147, 38); text-align: center; margin-top: 6px;">
                &nbsp;</div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you building the site in a table?

Comment: And thanks for the huge code dump.

Comment: Because its not for a entire site, its for an individual ebay description, sorry for the entire code I really just did not know how to ask the question without the full info.  This code is the best template I have currently and unfortunately I need to work with it and build upon it. eBay does not allow certain scripts and codes so tables work for me because its a very stripped down and basic way to convey info in HTML.

That's why I considered it perhaps a software issue, the entire description loads a little different in Chrome Android.

Comment: and thanks for your pointed tone

Comment: Can you use `<div>`s instead?

Comment: <div>s  ? i would never enclose script out of proper code? What will any browser do with <div>s ??? really? This might be a user agent developer question beyond the scale of said otherwise. I am just looking for a reason my script consisting of basic HTML tables may load differently, not drama.

Comment: First off a `script` and `HTML` are two very different things. Secondly, I was just asking if using divs instead of tables is ok, no need to get lippy with me, good luck with that!

Comment: im sure you could probably use other styles as long as they are somewhat basic so <div>s instead would be fine